# Magento 2: Get base URL in web template

Tags: magento2, template, base-url

How can we get Magento 2 base URL in web template (.html file) ?

**Note:** I am talking about web template (.html file). Not about general templates file (.phtml file).

Comment: See my note in question. It is not duplicate.

Comment: @ManashviBirla Please remove duplicate flag.

Comment: Which HTML file are you making changes to?

Comment: Please accept the answer if it's useful to you :)

Answer (score 3):

=> **Set URL in the JS file :**

First of all, Add `mage/url` to the list of dependencies.

Then, Add the following function to the knockout JS file:

```
getBaseUrl: function() {
    return url.build('<modulename>/<controllername>/<actionname>');
},
```

**=> Use Knockout to set the href :**

```
<a data-bind="attr: { href: getBaseUrl() }">Link Text</a>
```

**Then, clear Varnish and browser cache.**

Comment: I have only .html file to access. I don't have JS file access. How can I do ?

Comment: follow this answer. Add this function in related knockout js file & then add attribute data-bind in your anchor tag as like this format